# How to generate a random number if there is no input from the keyboard

Tags: java

I have been given help on how to generate a random name if input from keyboard is "". How do I do the same to generate a random number if input is ""? input "please enter the first number: " out - if no value is entered "" then generate random number.

```
package username;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class UserName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String user_Name1;
        System.out.print("Please enter the first username: ");
        user_Name1 = input.nextLine();
        if (user_Name1.equals("")) {
            String[] random = {"Luke", "Leia", "Hans", "Darth" , "Vader" , "Chewbacca"};
            user_Name1 = random[(int) (Math.random() * random.length)];
        }

        System.out.println("" + user_Name1);

        System.out.print("Please enter the first number: ");
        int user_number1 = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Comment: Do you understand what your current code does? What `(Math.random() * random.length)` does? That's all you need.

Comment: hi @Amongalen to be honest i dont- would you be kind enough to explain?

Comment: @Amongalen to be honest i don't really understand that line of code. Could you explain please?

Answer (score 0):

Here `input.nextInt();` means `Scanner.nextInt` is not taking `enterkey` as an valid input. So you can try by `input.nextLine()` and casting the value to an `Integer`.